# Advertencia: assignment from incompatible pointer type en codigo de listas enlazadas

Tags: c

tengo este código en c de ejemplo para entender el funcionamiento de listas enlazadas pero no se porque me salen las siguientes advertencias en las líneas 35 44 y 55, también tengo el mismo código pero hecho con funciones y sale el mismo warning

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
}persona;

typedef struct{
    persona p;
    struct Nodo *sig;
}Nodo;



int main(){
    //**********************************ASIGNAR****************************************//
    
    Nodo *lista = NULL;
    Nodo *NodoPersona = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    NodoPersona->p.edad = 44;
    strcpy(NodoPersona->p.nombre, "Juan");
    NodoPersona->sig = NULL;
    
    lista = NodoPersona;
    
    //***************************************ASIGNAR***********************************//
    
    NodoPersona = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    NodoPersona->p.edad = 15;
    strcpy(NodoPersona->p.nombre, "Matias");
    NodoPersona->sig = NULL;
    
    NodoPersona->sig = lista; //Warning
    lista = NodoPersona;    
//************************************ASIGNAR**************************************//

    NodoPersona = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    NodoPersona->p.edad = 20;
    strcpy(NodoPersona->p.nombre, "Valentin");
    NodoPersona->sig = NULL;
    
    (*NodoPersona).sig = lista; //Warning
    lista = NodoPersona;    
    
    //************************************MOSTRAR**************************************//
    Nodo *segLista = lista;
    
    while(segLista != NULL){
        
        printf("***********************************************\n");
        printf("Nombre: %s --------- Edad: %d\n" , segLista->p.nombre, segLista->p.edad);
        printf("***********************************************\n\n");
        segLista = segLista->sig; //Warning
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta estructura está mal definida:

```
typedef struct{
    persona p;
    struct Nodo *sig;
}Nodo;
```

El problema es que esta estructura no tiene un nombre, únicamente tiene un alias. Así, cuando, dentro de la propia estructura, estás creando el puntero `sig`, éste no es del tipo `Nodo` que esperas sino de ... francamente, ni idea.

Esta estructura deberías declararla así:

```
typedef struct Nodo{
    persona p;
    struct Nodo *sig;
}Nodo;
```

O así:

```
struct Nodo{
    persona p;
    struct Nodo *sig;
};

typedef struct Nodo Nodo;
```

Como prefieras de las dos maneras. Lo único importante es que le des un nombre a la estructura. En caso contrario la estructura no podrá contener punteros a otras instancias de dicha estructura